# Ansible json_query is adding extra characters to dictionary values

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam, ansible-2.x

I am encountering a strange problem with ansible, and I'm sure its just due to my lack of experience as I am relatively new to ansible (I've only been working with it for a couple weeks)

So, in short what I am trying to do is use the command module to run AWS CLI commands to list AWS access keys for a user then delete them from that user. The reason I am using CLI instead of iam module is because I believe there to be a bug with the IAM module in regard to removing access keys. Even when I specified state update and the access keys to remove and access key state remove it still would not remove access keys, or make them inactive when i set access key state to inactive.

The first task lists access keys for a given user and registers the output:

```
- name: List the access keys (if any) of the user(s) we just created
  vars:
    use_key: "{{ enable_access_keys }}"
  command: "aws iam list-access-keys --user-name {{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ iam_user_name_list }}"
  when: not use_key
  register: list_key_output
```

^Keep in mind that iam_user_name_list only contains 1 user at the moment, which is why i access results the way I do. I know this needs to be changed in the future.

Since the stdout from list_key_output looks like this

```
    "stdout": "{\n    \"AccessKeyMetadata\": [\n        {\n            \"UserName\": \"other-guy\", \n            \"Status\": \"Active\", \n            \"CreateDate\": \"2017-06-29T18:45:04Z\", \n            \"AccessKeyId\": \"removed\"\n        }\n    ]\n}",
```

I debug msg the stdout and register that to a variable test to give it proper json format without the slashes and newlines so I can use json_query to get the key from the stdout. I am using json query because AccessKeyId is not recognized as a key for the AccessKeyMetadata dictionary for whatever reason.

```
- name: list keys stdout
  debug:
    msg: "{{ list_key_output.results[0].stdout }}"
  register: test

- name: test variable output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test.msg.AccessKeyMetadata | json_query('[].AccessKeyId') }}"
```

At this point, I am successfully getting the access key from the stdout

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": [
        "correct access key here"
    ]
}
```

Now, I feed the access key to the delete CLI command like so

```
- name: Remove any access keys our new console user might have
  vars:
    use_key: "{{ enable_access_keys }}"
  command: "aws iam delete-access-key --access-key {{ test.msg.AccessKeyMetadata | json_query('[].AccessKeyId') }} --user-name other-guy"
  when: not use_key
  register: delete_key_output
```

This task fails due to an invalid access key being provided.

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "iam", "delete-access-key", "--access-key", "[u********************]", "--user-name", "other-guy"], "delta": "0:00:00.388902", "end": "2017-06-29 18:59:13.308230", "failed": true, "rc": 255, "start": "2017-06-29 18:59:12.919328", "stderr": "\nAn error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DeleteAccessKey operation: The specified value for accessKeyId is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters.", "stderr_lines": ["", "An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DeleteAccessKey operation: The specified value for accessKeyId is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

As you can see, when I pass the access key to the command, [u is prepended to the front of the access key and ] is appended to the back of it.

Why is this happening? How can I achieve my goal without having the 3 characters added to the access key making it invalid? I don't understand why this happens because when I debug msg the access key the same way i provide it to the command, it only shows the access key without [u in front and ] behind.

Sorry for the long post but I felt I really had to describe the situation to be able to get help here. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your exact question:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": [
        "correct access key here"
    ]
}
```

Note the `[` and `]` in the `msg` – this means that you print a list, that contain one element – `correct access key here` string.

When you try to convert list into string, you get it's Python interpretation `[u'correct access key here']`.

You need to get first element of a list:

```
{{ test.msg.AccessKeyMetadata | json_query('[].AccessKeyId') | first }}
```

P.S. but from my point of view, you are going in a wrong way. try to fix your issues with iam module.

Comment: Thanks. You were right, i could tell it was getting pretty convoluted the way i was going. It turns out my issue with the iam module was that even though the documentation says remove is an option, you can only do active/inactive for access_key_state.  Also, what would be the filter for the whole list just out of curiousity? all?

Comment: @astrade sorry, not sure what you mean by "filter for the whole list".